# How often to open a sqlite database

Tags: http, sqlite, node.js

I'm wondering about how often to open a sqlite database using node.js and [orlandov's node-sqlite plugin](https://github.com/orlandov/node-sqlite) for an http server.

Currently on every request to the server, I load a new instance of the database, then close it when reading is complete.

```
var db = sqlite.Database();
db.open("data.db", function (error) {
  ...
  //finally 
  db.close()
}
```

However, a user may make many requests within a short period of time. Would it be bad to hang onto a database instance for each connection for a while? Or is an open, close for each request the correct method?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Why close it at all? Open the database connection when you start up your node.js server, and keep it open indefinitely, ready to read/write when any connection needs it.